# Finding the rate of which theta changes

Tags: calculus

I am stuck on this question: "Point B moves from point A to point C at 2 cm/s in the accompanying diagram. At what rate is θ changing
when $x = 4$ cm?"
Here is the diagram:
[image]

I found that the $\dfrac{d\beta}{dt}$ for the triangle with the side length of $3$ to be equal to $0.25$cm/s. I used the smallest angle for that triangle to be $\beta$, where the lengths $3$ and $5 $ meet. I found $\beta$ by doing $\cot \beta = 3/x$, then derived that, then substituted $\dfrac{dx}{dt}$ (rate of $2$cm/s) into the equation and then solved for $\beta$ to get $0.25$cm/s. Is this the right way?

Comment: Hey, [here's](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) a quick guide to formatting math in here. I'll do it for you in this post so you can do it yourself from the next post onwards

Comment: @user2661923 it is clearly marked that AC = 4cm. The question asks for the point in time when AB = 4cm, i.e. when B and C coincide.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Good catch - I didn't think of this interpretation.

Comment: The units of $d\beta/dt$ are radians/s, not cm/s. Note that $3$ is in fact $3$cm.